# 404 error on visiting images in project folder on tomcat7 on mac os (moutain lion)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, tomcat7

I was trying to configure tomcat 7 (tomcat 7.0.47) on eclipse (kepler), it works, and I deployed my project to tomcat 7 successfully, I could also visit my project by url like 'localhost:8080/myproject/view/login.xhtml', but I could not visit images that in myproject folder, neither of by url like 'localhost:8080/myproject/myimage.jpg'
and by includes it in a xhtml with  tag. Visiting images by url, it returns 404 error. But when I created a new folder in webapps folder manually and copied a image into this folder, I could visit the image by url like 'localhost:8080/mynewfolder/myimage.jpg
'. Why I could not visit images that in myproject folder? Please help.

Comment: What kind of project is it? Was the image literally in the root of the project? Does that path deploy to the server?

Comment: It is a web application project. That path deploy to the server correctly, and I could visit xhtml page in project folder. My images in folder that the path like 'TOMCAT_WEBAPPS/myproject/view/images' (of course this folder deploy to the server correctly.), I could not visit images in this folder, and then I tried to copy image file to the root of the project (in tomcat webapps folder), it has the same outcome.